# Multiple views in Android

Tags: java, android, background-image, textview, setcontentview

I have a background image:

```
android:background="@drawable/bg">
```

and a TextView:

```
final TextView theTimer = new TextView(this);
```

If I use setContentView I can only place one of them on the screen.
How can I fit them both in one activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this -

> my_layout.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/ll"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:background="@drawable/bg">
    </LinearLayout>
```

> Activity code

```
setContentView(R.layout.my_layout);
final TextView theTimer = new TextView(this);
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewByID(R.id.ll);
ll.addView(theTimer);
```

Comment: or better yet, put the textview in the xml too.

Comment: then create `TextView` in xml file also why to add it programmatically.

Comment: I just felt like adding it programmatically. Does it have any negative impact on performance?

Answer (score 0):

Create 
 `RelativeLayout` create `ImageView`

```
  RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    ImageView img = new ImageView(this);
    img.setImageResource(R.drawable.your_drawable);


    TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
    tv1.setText("B");
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams =new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    tv1.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

    layout.addView(img);
    layout.addView(tv1);

    setContentView(layout);
```